# SVG - Change fill color on button click

Tags: jquery, svg

I've done a simple test svg-image.

I would like to make toggle buttons so when I click on btn-test1, the path1 will be fill="#000" and the others "#FFF". I'm going to make a map with around 40 different paths, but I'm trying this first (don't know if it's possible) ?

**Here's the HTML so far:**

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">

<path id="path1" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M291.451,51.919v202.54c0,0,164.521,119.846,140.146,0
    C407.227,134.613,291.451,51.919,291.451,51.919z"/>

<path id="path2" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M169.595,150.844c0,0-76.24,69.615-40.606,128.309
    c35.634,58.695,155.798-51.867,151.654-85.993C276.498,159.034,177.054,89.42,169.595,150.844z"/>

<path id="path3" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M40.332,90.466c0,0-39.911,76.119-2.691,87.83
    c37.22,11.71,78.923-46.844,56.054-78.462C70.826,68.216,40.332,90.466,40.332,90.466z"/>
</svg>

</div>

<button class="btn" id="btn-test1">Test 1</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn-test2">Test 2</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn-test3">Test 3</button>
```

**EDIT: This javascript solved it**

```
<script>
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('#path1, #path2, #path3').css({ fill: "#ffffff" });
var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
$('#path' + currentId +'').css({ fill: "#000" });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('<path-id>').setAttribute('fill', '<new-fill-color>');` ??

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are looking for the `fill` property.

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/P6t2B/**

For example:

```
$('#btn-test1').on("click", function() {
    $('#path1').css({ fill: "#ff0000" });
});
```

Comment: Nice! Working just fine. As I mentioned, I'm going to make an image with around 40 different paths and want to .toggle the fill. But I used your code and modified it and it now works great (se my edit)

Comment: Thank you a thousand times. I've been fighting with this stupid code for hours and you fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

Do this (just a small example ):

```
$(function(){
    $("#btn-test1").on("click",function(){
        $("#path1").attr("fill","#0000");   

    });
});
```

This will fill the path1 with #0000

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {

        //Redo XML
        jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
            var $img = jQuery(this);
            var imgID = $img.attr('id');
            var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
            var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

            jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
                // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
                var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

                // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
                if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                    $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
                }
                // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
                if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                    $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
                }

                // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
                $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

                // Replace image with new SVG
                $img.replaceWith($svg);

            }, 'xml');

        });

    });

    function changeColor(color)
    {

        //obj Father
        $("#imgSvg").css("fill", color);
        //objs children
        $('#imgSvg').children().css('fill', color);
    }
    </script>




    <img id="imgSvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="svg" src="imgTest.svg"/>

    <br />
    <br />

    <button onclick="changeColor('#C0C0C0')">Gray</button>
    <button onclick="changeColor('#FFF')">White</button>
    <button onclick="changeColor('#000')">Black</button>
```