# how to split image and fill different color

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

[image]

As this picture, how to use matlab code to split it into different parts, and then fill color in it? In addition, how to set gradient color in the second code ???

Here is the picture segmentation code:

```
clc
rgb=imread('sample1.bmp');
bw=im2bw(rgb2gray(rgb),.8);
bw=medfilt2(bw);
planes=bwareaopen(bw,800);
D=mat2gray(bwdist(imcomplement(planes)));
stats=regionprops(D>.8,'Centroid');
planes_centroid=cat(1,stats.Centroid);
planes_mask=false(size(bw));     
planes_mask(sub2ind(size(bw),round(planes_centroid(:,2)),...
        round(planes_centroid(:,1))))=1;
M=imimposemin(imcomplement(D),planes_mask);
L=watershed(M);
r=L & planes;
stats=regionprops(r,'BoundingBox','Centroid')
bb=cat(1,stats.BoundingBox);
c=cat(1,stats.Centroid);
figure,imshow(planes)
hold on
for i=1:length(stats)
   rectangle('Position',bb(i,:),'EdgeColor','b')
   plot(c(i,1),c(i,2),'r*')
   text(c(i,1)-5,c(i,2)-10,num2str(i))
end
%second code
clc;clf;close all;clear all;
color=cell(4,1);
for i=1:4
input=imread(['heartspline2_4_',num2str(i)],'bmp');  
figure,imshow(input);
BW=im2bw(input,graythresh(input));
[B,L]=bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');
for k=1:length(B)
   boundary=B{k};
   ind=size(boundary(:,2));
   plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'k','LineWidth',2);
   hold on;
   axis off;
   if (k==1)
       patch(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'w');
   else
       patch(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),???);
   end
end
saveas(gca,['y_','heartspline2_4_',num2str(i)],'bmp')
close(gcf)
end
```

Comment: You can convert the image to svg (lots of free online tools), then it's easy to change colors of paths, look at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211890/svg-change-fill-color-on-button-click

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should research and try by yourself. Then if you have a problem with the code come and ask your specific problem, while sharing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i need to process it in matlab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`bwlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) to assign different index to each image region:

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Iya.jpg');  %// read image
bw = img(:,:,1) > 128;  %// convert to binary mask
lb = bwlabel(bw,4);  %// extract distinct regions
```

The result:

```
figure; imshow(lb, [], 'border', 'tight'); colormap(rand(256,3));
```

[image]

---

If you want a gradient effect to the colors, you can

```
[x y] = meshgrid(linspace(0,1,size(bw,2)), linspace(0,1,size(bw,1)));
rand('seed',543310);
rgb_lb = ind2rgb(lb, rand(max(lb(:)+1),3)); %// convert to RGB color image
gx = x; 
gx(lb==1)=1;  %// use the horizontal gradient
gx = gx./max(gx(:));
```

Apply the gradient:

```
rgb_lb = bsxfun(@times, rgb_lb, gx);
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: @AnderBiguri tnx! I randomly picked the colors myself ;)

Comment: Quite neat, while noting the details (`4` in `bwlabel(bw,4)`).

Comment: that's right. some problem lies on the resolution,I still have one question. how to set gradient color to fill in?

Comment: @pring what gradient?

Comment: like the light blue to deep blue

Comment: @pring please see my edit: I outlined a method for adding gradient to the colors.

Comment: i have a question, what is lb?

Comment: @pring `lb` is the output of `bwlabel`: it assigns an index to each region in the image.

Comment: SIDENOTE: there is no need of `%//` , SO supports MATLAB!

Comment: Oh, that is lovely.

Comment: A further problem, if the colors are specially filled in the special area, how to build a color matrix to fix area 1,2,3... Here, the area label should be known from the picture so that the special color can be filled.

Comment: @pring in the answer the colors are set by `rand` command. If you have a specific map from region index to color you can feed it to ind2rgb I stead

Comment: Thank you! I have found the index out and color it.