# how to fill gradient color from light yellow to dark yellow?

Tags: matlab, colors

[image]
With matlab, I don't know how patch can make gradient color vertically in this picture. Here I just want a simple color gradient. I have used bwboundaries to catch the edge function and fill pure color just like this:

```
for i=1:4
  input=imread(['heartspline2_4_',num2str(i)],'bmp');  
  figure,imshow(input);
  BW=im2bw(input,graythresh(input));
  [B,L]=bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');
  for k=1:length(B)
      boundary=B{k};
      plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'k','LineWidth',2);
      fvc=[1 1 0;1 0 0;0 0 1];
      hold on;
      axis off;
      if (k==1)
          patch(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'w');
      else
          p=patch(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'y');
      end
  end
      saveas(gca,['y_','heartspline2_4_',num2str(i)],'bmp')
      close(gcf)
end
```

Comment: I guess this is a follow up question, please link to the other one. You want the filling to be a gradient? In which direction? A gradient of color, or a gradient of intensity?

Comment: Thank you for your question. I have modified my expression.

Comment: Also, consider accepting the other answer as valid.

Comment: OK, that's right!

Comment: look at [`doc patch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) the more advanced examples show how to have a color gradient on the patch.

Comment: The example is so simple to extend to this case. The image there has just 11 vertices. I don't know how to build faces and cdatas in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Following Shai's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124177/how-to-split-image-and-fill-different-color) in his answer in your other question:

```
  %% Load image %%
close all; clear all; clc;
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO8Nd.jpg');  %// read image
bw = img(:,:,1) > 128;  %// convert to binary mask
lb = bwlabel(bw,4);  %// extract distinct regions

%%

%% Create as many colors as needed
% example: 2

cmap=rand(2,3);  % make this yellow if needed

% lets convert to HSV, we can tune the intesity of the image better here
cmap=rgb2hsv(cmap);

% for each color, lets crate a set of colors.

for ii=1:size(cmap,1);


       colors{ii}= [cmap(ii,1)*ones(1,size(img,2)); cmap(ii,2)*ones(1,size(img,2)); linspace(0.3,1,size(img,2))].';
       %  Modify the limits of linspace
       % to achieve control over the limits
end

% Now we have the colors, lets create an image of vertical colors and mask
% it
cimage=zeros(size(img,1),size(img,2),3); % empthy color image
finalimage=cimage;
for ii=1:size(colors,2)
    colors{ii}=hsv2rgb(colors{ii});
    cimage=permute(reshape(repmat(colors{ii},[size(img,1),1,1]),[size(img,2),size(img,1),3]),[2,1,3]); % there is probably a simpler way 
    finalimage=finalimage+cimage.*repmat((lb==ii),[1 1 3]);
end


figure; imshow(finalimage, [], 'border', 'tight');
```

If you understand the code properly, you will be able to do it for vertical gradient. I accidentally did horizontal, but should be alright. The code is commented, but do not hesitate to ask. The steps are the following

- Create random colors, as many as desired. In this case 2
- convert to [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)
- Create a range of `V` values, that represent "light"
- Repeat that list of colors for every row on the image
- mask it with the labels to just add it to the areas of that label

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It is harder to understand than Shai's code, but finally I understand these. HSV is easily to think. The image process is based on the index. I have one more question, how to set the background transparent?

Comment: @pring You'd need a 4th channel, an RGBA image. The last one is transparency!

Comment: how to extent it based on your code or Shai's code?

Comment: @pring the first 4 lines are copy pasted from his answer