# Scatter plot in Matlab: same colour to same class

Tags: matlab, colors, scatter-plot

I have a matrix `A`  in Matlab of size `ax2` and a vector `class` of size `ax1`. The vector `class` contains integers from `1` to `237`. `class(i)` tells the class `A(i,:)` belongs to. For example

```
clear
rng default
a=10000;
A=randn(a,2);
class=randi(237,a,1);
```

I would like to do a scatter plot of `A(:,1)` on `A(:,2)` assigning the same colour to points in the same class. However, how can I generate 237 colors? I would be fine with having 237 nuances of blue for example, but I don't know if this is even possible in Matlab.

Comment: Note: `class` is a MATLAB function. If you use it as a variable, you are hiding the real function, and that may cause serious errors later. I suggest renaming `class` to `class_data` or some other non-MATLAB name.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate `n` amount of colors, the easiest way (if you have no constrains) is to simply get a colormap.

```
colors=colormap_of_your_choice(n);
```

Example:

```
colors=parula(237);
```

---

Check MATLABs colormap names [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#buc3wsn-1-map).

I added few more in [this FEX submission](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51986-perceptually-uniform-colormaps).

You can find [even](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45208-colorbrewer-attractive-and-distinctive-colormaps?s_tid=FX_rc1_behav) [more](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/57773-cmocean-perceptually-uniform-colormaps?s_tid=FX_rc2_behav) in FEX.

You can find how to create your custom colormaps with `n` colors [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133394/how-to-fill-gradient-color-from-light-yellow-to-dark-yellow/40134579#40134579).