# how to make smooth and remove the white edge? Besides, why the black lines arise in my answer? How to solve it?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, rgb

Based on [Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124177/how-to-split-image-and-fill-different-color) and [Biguri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133394/how-to-fill-gradient-color-from-light-yellow-to-dark-yellow/40134579?noredirect=1#comment67566319_40134579)'s codes and comments, I have finished a color picture like this:

[image]

A problem arises, how to remove the white edge and make it smooth? One solution may be to build `3x3` matrix or bigger and average. But the calculations should be large for every white-edge points. Or there may be some useful functions in *Matlab* to deal well with this problems?[image]

Comment: Why are you posting image in `jpg` format?  `jpg` format is a [lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) format, that creates artifacts. Please replace the image to `png` format.

Comment: You are doing great job with this! Neat, really! Im happy that you took the time to read and modify our answers!

Comment: Thank you for your guide. That's fun to make it possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a license for the image processing toolbox, you can try using for example `medfilt2` to apply a median filter on the image. A 11 by 11 median filter should do the trick. It is not very difficult to reimplement the filter yourself if you don't have the toolbox.

This is just one of the possibilities, you can use many different filters that will have different impacts on sharpness ang edge removal.

Edit:
Here is a quick median filter implementation (it may contain errors and could be optimized):

```
function ret = imageMedianFilter(im, np)
if(size(np,2) == 1)
    npx = np;
    npy = np;
else
    npx = np(1);
    npy = np(2);
end
ret = zeros(size(im,1),size(im,2));
for xpos = 1:size(im,1)
    for ypos = 1:size(im,2)
        curval = double(0);
        if(xpos + npx - 1) > size(im,1)
            npixels_x = size(im,1) - xpos + 1;
        else
            npixels_x = npx;
        end
        if(ypos + npy - 1) > size(im,2)
            npixels_y = size(im,2) - ypos + 1;
        else
            npixels_y = npy;
        end
        a = im(xpos:xpos+npixels_x-1 , ypos:ypos+npixels_y-1);
        a = reshape(a,1,size(a,1)*size(a,2));
        curval = median(a);
        ret(xpos , ypos) = curval;
    end
end
ret = uint8(ret);
end
```

You can use it on R,G and B components as shown by Rotem below:

`RGB = cat(3, imageMedianFilter(RGB(:,:,1), [11,11]), imageMedianFilter(RGB(:,:,2), [11,11]), imageMedianFilter(RGB(:,:,3), [11,11]));`

(assuming your image is named RGB).

Comment: I tried `medfilt2`, and it's giving a poor result. Please post source code, and result image.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, 11x11 gives better results. Unfortunately, I have no image processing toolbox license at hand, only a reimplementation. Otherwise, a gaussian filter like `imgaussfilt` should be ok but will decrease edge sharpness more than a median filter. It's up to the original poster to choose what is acceptable for him.

Comment: OK, it's working, but you need to apply filter on R, G and B separately: `RGB = cat(3, medfilt2(RGB(:,:,1), [11,11]), medfilt2(RGB(:,:,2), [11,11]), medfilt2(RGB(:,:,3), [11,11]));`

Comment: I don't have any license for the toolbox!

Comment: Thank you. I have to read it carefully and understand the codes. Besides, do you know how to solve the black lines question in my answer through patch average method?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. I take n*n patch to average the near RGB. But there is a problem arising. Why the right down side of processed picture showing black lines?

```
clc;clf;close all;clear all; 
img = imread('sample2color_t1.bmp');  %// read image
bw = img(:,:,1) > 128;  %// convert to binary mask
[lb,lab] = bwlabel(bw,4);  %// extract distinct regions
[a,b,c]=size(img);
R=ones(a,b);
G=ones(a,b);
B=ones(a,b);

%I have omitted other colors process codes. Below it is the white edges code.
r=[];c=[];
[r,c] = find(lb ==0);
for i=1:length(r)
  R(r(i),c(i))=1;
  G(r(i),c(i))=1;
  B(r(i),c(i))=1; 
end
scale=5;%步长1,8连通
for i=1:length(r)
  sumR=0;sumG=0;sumB=0;
  for j=0:2*scale
    for k=0:2*scale
        sumR=sumR+R(r(i)-scale+j,c(i)-scale+k);
        sumG=sumG+G(r(i)-scale+j,c(i)-scale+k);
        sumB=sumB+B(r(i)-scale+j,c(i)-scale+k);
    end
  end
  R(r(i),c(i))=sumR/(2*scale+1)^2;
  G(r(i),c(i))=sumG/(2*scale+1)^2;
  B(r(i),c(i))=sumB/(2*scale+1)^2;
end

imPaint=cat(3,R,G,B);
figure;
imshow(imPaint);
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it should be an edit or an answer: you solve the question, but ask another one , which you should not do

Comment: Also: maybe the average is black! Try to average, but ignore blacks.

Comment: How to ignore blacks? I have added a judge when RGB<0.05, the RGB value obtains white color. But the black lines still exists. I don't know what happens in this case.